# Getting "404 Not Found" error on one specific API route

Tags: python, api, error-handling, routes, postman

I am getting the following error when I try to test one specific route using http://127.0.0.1:5000/planets.

404 Not Found Error

[image: 1]

The other routes I have made work perfectly fine. Here is the route that is not working, along with the class and the instantiations for it.

```
@app.route('/planets', methods=['GET'])
def planets():
    planets_list = Planet.query.all()
    result = planets_schema.dump(planets_list)
    return jsonify(result)

class PlanetSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('planet_id', 'planet_name', 'planet_type', 'home_star', 'mass', 'radius', 'distance')

planet_schema = PlanetSchema()
planets_schema = PlanetSchema(many=True)
```

I am using Postman to test the route and I have also made sure to select 'GET' in Postman while testing this so that it matches the route method in my code.

Postman URL bar

[image: 2]

I have tried updating packages, rolling packages back to previous versions, making sure I have all the correct/needed imports, killing all python instances and trying again, killing all Postman instances and trying again, and restarting my computer. I am making this API as part of a class I am taking and the teacher provides you with a file that has the correct code in it. I have compared and even copied/pasted the same pieces of code from the teacher's file and I still get the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add a slash '/' at the end of your URL in the postman, please change `http://127.0.0.1:5000/planets` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/planets/` and make request again

Comment: I have already tried that and unfortunately I get the same error with or without an extra slash at the end.